# With Shopify API I'm getting the error ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed. Response code = 404. Response message = Not Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I've been working on this APP for Shopify using the Shopify API gem for RoR. Everything was fine until today.

Before today I was doing this to retrieve a product:

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.find(3685278401)
```

And that was retrieving a Shopify product. However today I was working on the APP, and now every time that I try to find a product I receive the following error:

```
ActiveResource::ResourceNotFound: Failed.  Response code = 404.  
Response message = Not Found.
from /Users/enriquesalceda/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activeresource-4.0.0/lib/active_resource/connection.rb:144:in `handle_response'
```

I don't know how to fix this... on the other hand if I want to get all the products

```
ShopifyAPI::Product.all
```

That works.

Could someone help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this. I had trouble thinking I was looking up a product as well and getting a 404 not found. Thought my code was perfect but I was using a Variant ID that belonged to a product. So the find was not receiving any data.

So instead of: `ShopifyAPI::Product.find(product_id)`

you would use: `ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(product_id)` where product_id is actually a variant ID.

Answer (score 0):

If the product does not exist, you get a 404 error. There is nothing to fix. If you ask for a product that does exist, use a rescue statement to capture the 404 and move on gracefully.